# INVALID_ARGUMENT error while using Google Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a dataflow job created from the custom template and trying to set up schedule using Google Cloud Scheduler.

These are my execution configurations:
Target type : HTTP

URL : https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects//locations//templates:launch?gcsPath=xyz

HTTP Method: POST

HTTP Headers:
Content-Type : application/json
User-Agent : Google-Cloud-Scheduler

Body:
{}

Auth Header : Add OAUTH Token

Service Account : newly created one with Cloud Scheduler Admin, Dataflow Admin, Cloud Functions Invoker

Scope: https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects//locations//templates:launch

**I am encountering below error :**

{
"insertId": "1e7pitfe7pugf",
"jsonPayload": {
"targetType": "HTTP",
**"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",**
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
"jobName": "projects//locations/us-central1/jobs/my-job",
"url": "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects//locations/us-central1/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://xyz"
},
"httpRequest": {},
"resource": {
"type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
"labels": {
"location": "us-central1",
"job_id": "my-job",
"project_id": ""
}
},
"timestamp": "2024-02-27T06:16:00.506128456Z",
"severity": "ERROR",
"logName": "projects//logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
"receiveTimestamp": "2024-02-27T06:16:00.506128456Z"
}

When I tried to use **OIDC token**, I get **UNATHENTICATED** error

Can someone please help me on this?
Thanks in advance

1. I tried putting base64 encode of action in the message body, resulted in the same error
2. I tried by creating new Service Account with different permission access - same error
3. Found on stackoverflow that disabling and re-enabling Cloud Scheduler API helped someone, dint work for me
4. tried by using target type as pubsub and created the pubsub topic - same error

Comment: Hi @user12499294, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.